# RSpec code example basics with CRUD method calls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, crud

After generate rspec:install in a Rails 3 project any new scaffolding will include some default specs. I'm confused about the get, post, put & delete methods and what they're actually being called on?

specifically, in this example, the line `delete :destroy, :id => "1"` is being called on what exactly? the controller? but the controller doesn't have a 'delete' method...though it does have `destroy`. but calling 'delete' on it shouldn't do anything so passing `:destroy` as an argument is meaningless... how does this work?

Here's a portion of the generated specs for a resources_controller. I've left out, but the same thing exists for `put :update` and `post :create` and `get :edit`, `:show`, `:new` & `:index`

```
#app/controllers/resources_controller.rb

describe ResourcesController do

  def mock_resource(stubs={})
    @mock_resource ||= mock_model(Resource, stubs).as_null_object
  end

  ...

  describe "DELETE destroy" do
    it "destroys the requested resource" do
      Resource.stub(:find).with("37") { mock_resource }
      mock_resource.should_receive(:destroy)
      delete :destroy, :id => "37"
    end

    it "redirects to the resources list" do
      Resource.stub(:find) { mock_resource }
      delete :destroy, :id => "1"
      response.should redirect_to(resources_url)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write controller specs, RSpec includes the ControllerExampleGroup module, which ["extends ActionController::TestCase::Behavior to work with RSpec."](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/master/lib/rspec/rails/example/controller_example_group.rb).

[ActionController::TestCase::Behavior](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb) is where these methods are defined.

Answer (score 2):

`get`, `post`, `put`, and `delete` are the HTTP verbs used in the request. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods

And yes, the following argument is the action being called on your controller, `:update`, `:create`, etc.

Comment: i understand the HTTP verbs...what I don't understand is how they work...here...in this test? are you saying "get" is a reserved word in Rails (or Ruby?) and I can use it anywhere? probably not. It's a method on *some* object...somewhere... but where? or what?

Comment: In this example, RSpec is using the built-in action controller test methods that rails ships with. Check out the source for these methods if you are interested https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb#L353